# Learning physics conceptually for a layman

Tags: soft-question, resource-recommendations, education, popular-science

Can anyone suggest a video or book that will allow the layman to grasp physics concepts in a conceptual manner?

Comment: What kind of physics? This is a pretty broad question as is, it would help if you narrowed it down.

Comment: http://phet.colorado.edu/en/simulations
Play around a bit with these :)

Answer (score 3):

One big foundation of physics is the law of gravitation and Richard Feynman explains it very nicely but with a lot of insight: [The Character of Physical Law](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=j3mhkYbznBk#!)

There are of course hundreds of other videos and books describing the concepts, just pick one that suits your style.

Comment: +1, I will add this little but great book "Six easy pieces" from Richard Feynman too

Answer (score 1):

For particle physics, a not-too well known but astonishingly good semi-popular book is t'Hooft's "[In Search of the Ultimate Building Blocks](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Search-Ultimate-Building-Blocks/dp/0521578833)".  It's unique in that, in addition to the usual topics - unification, quarks, Higgs mechanism etc, he treats topics such as **instantons** and the **triangle anomaly**.  Unheard of in the pop-sci realm !!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have "all subjects" covered I would recommend [Feynman's Lecture on Physics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feynman_Lectures_on_Physics). But you would not find anything about recent developments (this book is a classical from the 1960ies).